# Identification of two hypercubes in $\mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, euclidean-geometry, riemannian-geometry, analytic-geometry

Use the notation $k = (k_1,\ldots, k_d) \in \mathbb{R}^d$. How to see that the regions
$$
\Big \{ \, \, k \in \mathbb{R}^d \, \, :  \sum_{i=1}^d \cos(k_i) > 0 \, \, \Big \} \cap  \Big \{  k \in \mathbb{R}^d  : \| k  \|_\infty < \pi  \Big  \}
$$
and
$$
  \Big \{  k \in \mathbb{R}^d  : \| k  \|_1< \pi  \Big  \}
$$
are the same (if true)?

Comment: I think the sets in question are not hypercubes in the usual meaning of the word if $d\ge 3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems not to be true for $d\ge 3$. In the case $d=3$, your second set is an *octahedron*, while your first set is the intersection of a cube with this region:

[image]

This cannot give an octahedron.